# Control Linux rsyslog service from C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, daemon

I have a C++ application (running as a non-root user) which manipulates the rsyslog.conf configuration file. I then want to do something like

```
service rsyslog restart
```

from the C++ application (e.g. using execvp), so the new configuration takes effect.

In the .conf file, I could use $PrivDropToGroup and $PrivDropToUser to run the rsyslog daemon as a particular user. However, to restart the service I need root priviledges. I don't want to enable sudo for the user running the C++ application.

Is there a way to restart the service from the C++ application without resorting to sudo?

Comment: Could you make `root` the owner of the application binary and put the setuid bit on it?

Comment: no, the application cannot be run as root.

Comment: [systemd has a D-Bus API](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/) that might help with this, if you're using dbus-enabled systemd.